# Quotient of monotone functions is monotone?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f,g$ are monotone( say increasing) and differentiable and nonnegative. Both go from $\mathbb{R}^{\geq 1} \to \mathbb{R} $

Is $\frac{f}{g}$ also monotone ?

Comment: Did you try using the quotient rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Counterexample:**
Let $f(x) = e^x+5, g(x) = x$. 
$$\frac{f}{g}(x) = \frac{e^x+5}{x}$$

Can you tell me why $\displaystyle{\frac{f}{g}}$ is not necessarily monotone?

Comment: so you are claiming that $e^xx - e^x < 0 $?  in other words, $\frac{1}{x} > 1 $ which is false

Comment: I mean it is false your claim. your $f$ is increasing

Comment: It's not false at all. Plot the equation on a graph. This should work: http://fooplot.com/#W3sidHlwZSI6MCwiZXEiOiJlXngveCIsImNvbG9yIjoiIzAwMDAwMCJ9LHsidHlwZSI6MTAwMH1d

Comment: I mean it is false for $x \geq 1 $

Comment: Your question's conditions didn't specify that. Okay, now you've edited them...

Comment: I have updated my qs

Comment: Then translate the function....

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)=2x+\sin x,\ g(x)=x,\ 0\lt x\lt\infty$