# Is this claim true about the monotonicity of $\frac{\cosh 2 x^3 }{3\cosh 5 x^3 }$?

Tags: monotone-functions

I want to check the monotonicity of the function for $x>0$
$$\frac{\cosh  2 x^3 }{3\cosh  5 x^3 }$$
Computing the first derivative, it can be proved that it is negative and then the function is decreasing.

My question is can we claim that since $\,\cosh x^3\,$ is an increasing function for $x>0$, and since the numerator is less than the denominator, then, the function is decreasing?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What facts are you saying you already know, and what statement are you trying to deduce from it? In your first paragraph, "increasing" seems to contradict the first derivative being positive.

Comment: See the alternate form from this link https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative+ln%28cosh%282x%5E3%29%2F%283cosh%285x%5E3%29%29%29 .

Comment: @GregMartin It was a typo. I meant decreasing!

Comment: Your question seems to be asking whether this implication is true: if $f(x)$ is increasing and $f(x)<g(x)$, then $f(x)/g(x)$ is decreasing. This is definitely not true, as examples like $f(x)=1-1/x$, $g(x)=1$ show.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks. In your example, $f$ and $g$ are not of the same type. So, in the general case, it is not true.

Comment: But what does "same type" mean, exactly? Anyway, in general it's better to have these statements given precisely—that makes it easier to evaluate whether they're true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that by $y=x^3>0$

$$\frac{\cosh  2 x^3 }{3\cosh  5 x^3 }=\frac{\cosh  2y }{3\cosh  5 y }=\frac{e^{3y}(e^{4y}+1)}{3(e^{10y}+1)}$$

and $e^y=z>1$

$$\frac{e^{3y}(e^{4y}+1)}{e^{10y}+1}=\frac{z^3(z^4+1)}{z^{10}+1}=f(z)$$

and

$$f'(z)= \frac{z^2(-3z^{14}-7z^{10}+7z^4+3)}{(z^{10}+1)^2}$$

and

$$-3z^{14}-7z^{10}+7z^4+3=-3(z^{14}-1)-7z^4(z^6-1)<0$$

Comment: So, my claim is not true and we need to prove it. Thanks.

Comment: @charmin Yes indeed by your claim we can conclude that $f(x)<1$ but for monotonicity we need to prove that $f'(x)<0$. The way I've shown should simplify this evaluation.

Comment: @charmin I can't exclude there is sime other way to get the same conclusion in this partcular case. I'll take a look also on that. You are welcome! Bye

Comment: @charmin Refer to the related [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/548778/505767).